# Mock function not called when the mock is not at the top of the file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an React function component to validate the properties that get passed to it. When the mock is at the top of the file it works fine, like so:

```
const mockTrackList = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../components/Tracklist/VirtualTracklist', () => (props: TrackListProps) => {
    mockTrackList(props);
    return <div />
});

describe('Test the RequestList component', () => {
    it('test-title', async () => {
        flushSync(() => {
            render(
                <RequestList streamer={'streamer'} isStreamer={false} />
            );
        })

        await waitFor(async () => {
            expect(mockTrackList).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith([...]);
        });
    });
});
```

However, when done like this, the `mockTrackList` isn't called and the test fails:

```
const mockTrackList = jest.fn();
const mockComp = (props: TrackListProps) => {
    mockTrackList(props);
    return <div />
};

describe('Test the RequestList component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock('../components/Tracklist/VirtualTracklist', () => mockComp);
    });

    it('test-title', async () => {
        flushSync(() => {
            render(
                <RequestList streamer={'streamer'} isStreamer={false} />
            );
        })

        await waitFor(async () => {
            expect(mockTrackList).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith([...]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use the one that works? If the mock call isn't at the top level it doesn't get hoisted and therefore the mock isn't registered when the module under test imports (so it gets the real implementation).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to have one describe block with the actual component and one block with the mocked component. I could split it into two files but I prefer to keep it in one, if possible

Comment: Unless you also defer the import of the module you're testing, no that's not possible.

Comment: Answers should be an answer rather than part of the question 

Comment: @DaveNewton be the change you want to see in the world!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Too hard on mobile :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jonrsharpe suggested, deferring the module import solved my problem. Here is the updated beforeEach:

```js
    let RequestList: FC<RequestListProps>;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        jest.mock('../components/Tracklist/VirtualTracklist', () => mockComp);
        RequestList = (await import('../components/RequestList')).default;
    });
```